# How to hide angular 4/6 kendo grid numeric filter increase decrease icons? (spinners)

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

This is my kendo grid column

```
 <kendo-grid-column width="80" field="Savings" title="Savings" filter="numeric">
 </kendo-grid-column>
```

But when I put this one, there are two icons for the increase and decrease like this

[image]

I need to remove those icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
.k-dateinput .k-select, .k-numerictextbox .k-select {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  width: calc(8px + 1.4285714286em);
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: none !important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```